# Is it OK to pass hiring manager info to old boss?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, networking

I work in software. I have recently switched jobs, from Old Company to New Company, a few months back.

Old Company, among other things, hires out consultants. I am on good terms with Old Company, and have made a point about maintaining some sort of contact, but I am formally not associated with Old Company in any way anymore. Old Company is fairly small.

I like New Company just fine.

Old Company's top boss and founder is asking me for contact information to people with hiring decision power at New Company, and my consent to say I gave out this info, with the explicit intent to set up a business meeting, knowing that New Company at least is open to hiring consultants. New Company are currently not hiring, but might in the future.

Also, since I'm fairly new at New Company, I don't know how New Company would react to such a move.

I really have no idea what applies here, or how I should proceed?

1. Is this common?
2. Are there any legal issues I should be aware of?
3. Should I inform my boss at New Company about this request?
4. Should I comply? Politely refuse? Ghost the request?

I'd like to keep a good relationship with both, but ideally, I wouldn't want Old Company around, there was a reason I switched.

Comment: So ultimately you do not want to do it? As your question title indicates not if, can I not to, but how to do it.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul My gut says no, but I'm ambivalent. I don't personally have any recommendations for hires from Old Company.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to do it, the answer is simple - just don't. Politely tell your "old company top boss" that you don't feel comfortable with it.

If you do want to get involved, talk with your boss at the New Company first. Ask if that is something that would be of interest to them. If they agree, only then pass along the contact information.

This sort of connection happens all the time. But you do have to be careful.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this common?

Yes, quite so.

> Are there any legal issues I should be aware of?

Unlikely, but if you want to be sure: read your contract and employee handbook

> Should I inform my boss at New Company about this request?

You certainly can, but what exactly to tell them depends on the next point

> Should I comply? Politely refuse? Ghost the request?

Don't ghost. That's just rude.

Here is what's happening: your ex boss asks you to do little bit of marketing and sells work for them. There is nothing nefarious about it but you are also in no way obligated to accommodate them.

You are currently working at company B and their best interest should be your highest priority. If you feel that this may be something that company B would be interested in, it's perfectly fine to approach your new food chain and just ask. "Hey, my previous company does XYZ and would like to talk to you about it. If that's something you are interested in, I can make connections". They either will say "yes" or "no thanks" and you can simply relay this back to company A. If the powers at company B ask for your opinion, just be honest.

If you already know that B is not interested or you really don't want A in there in the first place, you just politely decline the request.